# finding the error for xml class?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

My class `activity_main.xml` don't work well. When I execute my program, appear an error, and create a new class empty, activity_main.out.xml.
this is the error:

[2013-01-10 11:05:20 - EstudandoSQLite] ActivityManager: Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front

Comment: This isn't an Error, this is a WARNING! It tries to tell you, that your app is already running.

Answer (score 4):

You are by mistake running hte xml file instead of the Application.
(In Eclipse) try: Window->Preferences->Run/Debug->Launching->Always launch the previously launched application instead of the other one.
The other text:

```
Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front
```

means that you restarted your app without making any changes and it is not an error.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to run the XML file instead of a java class file. Close and delete the `xml.out`. When you run the program you need to have the focus on a class file or click the arrow by the "run" button and choose your project instead of an xml file

Comment: I think you can prevent eclipse from running xml files.

Comment: I'm sure you are correct, I just have never messed with it. I just click the arrow and run the app, but good point